# Input feature to Feature maps

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Can anybody please explain this basic thing to me that how does a 192x28x28 input image gets reduced to a 16x28x28 feature maps using a 1x1 conv mapping. My question is about the understanding of what exactly happens when 192 goes to 16 ??

i know about ((I-2P-F)/S)+1, but what happens in the process of reducing depth.

Answer (score 1):

The 1x1 Convolution compresses the whole 192*28*28 input image (which could be read as 192 feature maps of `28px * 28px` pixels images) into a single 1*28*28 image. So far it reduces depth in the "feature map axis" to 1 while preserving the height and width of the original image.

But then... why do you get the 16? In a convolutional layer you can have different **kernels**. Basically each kernel is an indepentent filter with the same size. In your case it looks like your 1x1 Conv layer has 16 kernels by default, hence you get 16 28*28 images (one per kernel).